# How to use TypeScript correctly for map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have this DB, and I'm trying correctly map the types when using Map function. First time doing it so trying to learn but I'm stuck.

Db

```js
const db = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      contentType: ['video'],
      title: '1 to 1 Coaching: Sprinting Technique',
      author: {
        name: 'James',
        image: {
          alt: 'smiling.',
        },
      },
      image: {
        alt: 'Two footballers jostling for the ball with a coach watching in the background.',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

For now I'm just using sample type of `id` and `title` but even here I'm stuck on how to correctly map it so TS does not complain :(

App.tsx

```js
type Data = {
  id: number
  title: string
}

interface Customer {
  id: number
  title: string
}

export default function Box(): JSX.Element {
  const [data, setData] = useState([db])
  return (
    <>
      {data.map(
        ({
          data: {
            id,
            contentType,
            title,
            author: {
              name,
              img: { src, alt },
            },
            image: { src, alt },
          },
        }): JSX.Element => {
          console.log(id)
          return <div css={mainBox}></div>
        },
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Why are you creating a single-element array to iterate over? What's TypeScript's complaint?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-frost-r46zl?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: single element is an example it will have more from DB. Updated map to include all elements, i believe this is how it should look correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: There's a `data[x].author.image` in your db, but a `data[x].author.img` in `Box()`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has little to do with TS itself since the error is at object destructuring in parameters list of your `map` callback.

When you apply object destructuring to the argument of the function, JS/TS assigns properties of the object to distinct variables with the same name (unless they are objects and they are destructured in a similar way).

Let's have a look at `author` property destructuring:

```ts
...
            author: {
              name,
              img: { src, alt },
            },
...
```

This snippet will be treated as following:

`author.name` property will be assigned to distinct `name` variable. However,

`author.img` won't be assigned to distinct `img` variable since it is an object and it is desctructured. 
It's properties would be assigned to distinct variables `src` and `alt` respectively.

After that we have another property desturctured:

```ts
    image: { src, alt },
```

Again, `image` won't be assigned to distinct variable since it's object being destructured. But it's properties should.

It's properties are `src` and `alt`. And they should be set to variables with these names but we already have those names come from destructuring `author.img`.

So there is name collision in variables definition and that's why TS compiler raised an error.

You may fix this by assigning properties to new variable names, for example, the following way:

```ts
({
          data: {
            id,
            contentType,
            title,
            author: {
              name,
              img: { src: authorImgSrc, alt: authorImgAlt },
            },
            image: { src, alt },
          },
        }): JSX.Element => {
            // src refers to image.src, authorImgSrc refers to author.name.src
            // alt refers to image.alt, authorImgAlt refers to author.name.alt
        }
```

Here we explicitly assigned `author.img` properties to variables with different names so there is no name collision anymore.

The destructuring assignment technique might be really useful, there are more examples of it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

After that you might see that you might not even need `map` in the first place, because you used array destructuring here:

```ts
const [data] = useState([db]);
```

And after that you may have access to it's internals directly:

```ts
const {img} = data.data.author;
```

So you may want to either remove `.map` (and render db entry directly) or not use array destructuring in `data` variable initialization:

```ts
const data = useState([db]);
```